# Data Studio | How to write case for >= or <= to filter data for Date dimension

Tags: looker-studio

**Requirement:** My data table has 2 fields i.e. Name and Date of joining (DOJ). I want to count users who joined on or before 30-Jan-21.

**Solution tried:** I created a calculated field using CASE i.e.

CASE WHEN CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", DOJ) AS NUMBER ) <= 20210130 THEN DOJ END.

**Issue**: After creating the field, I aggregated it by count and used the field in metric but its not giving count of users who joined on or before 30-Jan-21.

**Data Table preview**

| Name | DOJ |
| --- | --- |
| John Smith | 04/01/2021 |
| Dexter Morgan | 13/01/2021 |
| Debra Morgan | 18/01/2021 |
| Kyle Butler | 21/01/2021 |
| Rita Benett | 25/01/2021 |
| Angel Batista | 31/01/2021 |
| Maria LaGuerta | 01/02/2021 |
| Vince Masuka | 17/02/2021 |
| Joey Quinn | 26/03/2021 |
| Arthur Mitchell | 05/04/2021 |
| Thomas Matthews | 25/05/2021 |

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**
I created a field to convert **Date** into **Number** and created another calculated field where I used both the conditions i.e. >= and <= and got the desired result.

Formula for converting Date to text:
CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", DOJ) AS NUMBER)

Formula for counting DOJ's in Month of Jan'21 i.e. on and before 30-Jan-21
CASE WHEN DOJ <= 20210130 AND DOJ >=20210101 then DOJ END